# Will there be any site events for the Apple Watch live stream?

Tags: discussion

On March 9 - 10 AM PDT, Apple has a live event.

http://www.apple.com/live/2015-mar-event/

Answer (score 1):

Why yes - [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat) is a good place to follow along.

In addition, these resources are covering the event:

- http://www.apple.com/live/2015-mar-event/
- Apple TV - look for Apple Events using this icon:

  [image]
- http://liveblog.macobserver.com/